# Brew doctor warning for /usr/local/lib

Tags: homebrew

executing `brew doctor` I have the following warning:

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libklcsagt.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libklcskca.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libklcsnagt.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libklcsrt.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libklcsstd.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libklcstr.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libklmspack.0.1.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libklmspack.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libklmspack.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libz.1.2.6.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libz.dylib
```

Is there a way to fix this? I don't want to delete them since it could cause problems (not sure about this).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there’s a way to fix: delete them.

However, as `brew doctor` says:

> Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
>   with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
>   working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

In other words: you don’t need to address any of the warnings from `brew doctor` if you don’t have any issue with Homebrew.